# Windows firewall: How to change existing rules using netsh

Tags: windows

I can create new rules using

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule...
```

and Delete them using

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule...
```

But I am not able to find a way to change existing rules.

Right now I implemented a logic where I check if the rule exists and if the rule does exist then I delete it and then I insert a modified rule. But in this approach, I need to keep track of previous rule configurations. For example, if I just want to disable the rule that I just cannot delete the existing rule and write a new rule without knowing what were other configurations of that rule.

Is there a better way to do the same where I want to change one field but keep everything the same using bat file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule` command, which "sets new values for properties of an existing rule." For example, to disable all rules named "Web Server":

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Web Server" new enable=no
```

See `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule /?` for more details. Notably, additional filters (e.g. `profile=private` to only affect the Private profile) go before `new` and other fields to change go after `new`.