# Missing Parameters in PowerShell Firewall Outbound Rule Command

Tags: powershell, firewall

I have an existing Outbound Rule in my firewall with a set of specified IP addresses. For enhanced security, I want to append additional IP addresses to this rule using a shell script. I am trying to execute the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Outbound Rule Name" remoteip=IP_ADDRESS1,IP_ADDRESS2,...
```

However, I encounter the following error message:

```
One or more essential parameters were not entered. Verify the required parameters, and reenter them.
```

I initially suspected that there might be an issue with the rule itself, but when I ran the command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Outbound Rule Name"
```

It confirmed that the rule is active and functioning. I am perplexed about what might be wrong with the add rule command and which essential parameters are missing.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76025461/add-windows-firewall-rule-for-multiple-ips-using-netsh-exe might help.

Comment: `add rule` is for adding _new_ rules. May I suggest this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1661496/219095

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One or more essential parameters were not entered

You've missed two vital parameters: `dir` and `action`. These parameters define the rule's ***direction***, which can be either **inbound** or **outbound**, and the ***action*** it should perform, whether **allowing** or **denying**.

To be specific, include `dir=out` and `action=allow` parameters and their value to the command.

#### PowerShell

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Outbound Rule Name" dir=out remoteip=IP_ADDRESS1,IP_ADDRESS2,... action=allow
```

When it comes to **modifying existing firewall rules using NETSH**, utilize the `set rule` command and ensure that the `new` keyword is included, but it should not be placed as the final parameter when updating existing rules.

#### PowerShell

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Outbound Rule Name" new dir=out remoteip=IP_ADDRESS1,IP_ADDRESS2,... action=allow
```

### Supporting Resource

> **`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule /?`**
>
> ```
> Usage: add rule name=<string>
>       dir=in|out
>       action=allow|block|bypass
>
>
>       [program=<program path>]
>       [service=<service short name>|any]
>       [description=<string>]
>       [enable=yes|no (default=yes)]
>       [profile=public|private|domain|any[,...]]
>       [localip=any|<IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
>       [remoteip=any|localsubnet|dns|dhcp|wins|defaultgateway|
>          <IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
>       [localport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|RPC|RPC-EPMap|IPHTTPS|any (default=any)]
>       [remoteport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|any (default=any)]
>       [protocol=0-255|icmpv4|icmpv6|icmpv4:type,code|icmpv6:type,code|
>          tcp|udp|any (default=any)]
>       [interfacetype=wireless|lan|ras|any]
>       [rmtcomputergrp=<SDDL string>]
>       [rmtusrgrp=<SDDL string>]
>       [edge=yes|deferapp|deferuser|no (default=no)]
>       [security=authenticate|authenc|authdynenc|authnoencap|notrequired
>          (default=notrequired)]
> ```

> **`netsh advfirewall firewall set rule /?`**
>
> ```
> Usage: set rule
>       group=<string> | name=<string>
>       [dir=in|out]
>       [profile=public|private|domain|any[,...]]
>       [program=<program path>]
>       [service=service short name|any]
>       [localip=any|<IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
>       [remoteip=any|localsubnet|dns|dhcp|wins|defaultgateway|
>          <IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
>       [localport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|RPC|RPC-EPMap|IPHTTPS|any]
>       [remoteport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|any]
>       [protocol=0-255|icmpv4|icmpv6|icmpv4:type,code|icmpv6:type,code|
>          tcp|udp|any]
>       new
>       [name=<string>]
>       [dir=in|out]
>       [program=<program path>
>       [service=<service short name>|any]
>       [action=allow|block|bypass]
>       [description=<string>]
>       [enable=yes|no]
>       [profile=public|private|domain|any[,...]]
>       [localip=any|<IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
>       [remoteip=any|localsubnet|dns|dhcp|wins|defaultgateway|
>          <IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
>       [localport=0-65535|RPC|RPC-EPMap|any[,...]]
>       [remoteport=0-65535|any[,...]]
>       [protocol=0-255|icmpv4|icmpv6|icmpv4:type,code|icmpv6:type,code|
>          tcp|udp|any]
>       [interfacetype=wireless|lan|ras|any]
>       [rmtcomputergrp=<SDDL string>]
>       [rmtusrgrp=<SDDL string>]
>       [edge=yes|deferapp|deferuser|no (default=no)]
>       [security=authenticate|authenc|authdynenc|notrequired]
>
> For 'set' commands, the 'new' keyword must be present and must not be the last argument provided.
> ```

Comment: I assumed you are trying to **allow** the outbound connections to the IP address, but obviously if you are **blocking** —then it should be `action=block`.